# How do I make a simple dice roll to display in chat as a number?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have a button in the world that when pressed will roll a number between 1 and 20 using the `/random roll 1..20` command and then display it to everyone in chat, something like "You rolled a 5". The problem is I don't know how to format the command in a command block.

I thought it would be simple enough but I don't know the first thing about formatting execute commands.

Answer (score 4):

> value|roll
>
> Whether or not to notify other players of the results when extracting random numbers. If this is `value`, then the results are displayed only to the player using the command. If this is `roll`, then the results are revealed to all players.

from [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/random#Arguments)

As shown in the quote, `/random roll` already tells all players "*[player] rolled a [number] (from 1 to 20)*", however, if you want to display this in a custom way (e.g. *An [number] was rolled!*), then you need to first create a scoreboard to store the randomly rolled value:

```
/scoreboard objectives add random dummy
```

(You can call the scoreboard any name, in this case it's "random".)

Then you can roll a random number and store it to the scoreboard using `/execute`:

```
/execute as @s store result score Random random run random value 1..20
```

(Use random value rather than random roll, otherwise it will tell all players before you run the last command, which will use the "*[player] rolled a [number] (from 1 to 20)*".)

Finally, you can run this command to send a chat message to all players that includes the scoreboard value:

```
/tellraw @a [{"text":"A "},{"score":{"name":"Random","objective":"random"}},{"text":" was rolled"}]
```

---

To change the text, use this base command:

```
/tellraw @a [{"score":{"name":"Random","objective":"random"}}]
```

Then add {"text":"*[text contents]*"} as many times as needed, replacing *[text contents]* with whatever text you need. Make sure to seperate each section with commas.

Source: [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute) and in-game testing.